# disable javamelody grails plugin completely

Tags: grails, groovy, grails-plugin

I am trying to figure out how to disable javamelody grails plugin completely. Following http://www.grails.org/plugin/grails-melody, I set javamelody.disabled = true in GrailsMelodyConfig.groovy. For some reason, this disables monitoring in a sense that I cannot navigate to myapp/monitoring to view info. More debugging showed that even if I disabled it, it is still calling doWithDyanmicMethod which adds invokeMethod on each services.

Is there something else I am missing? If it adds invokeMethod on each services, this defeats the point of disable.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://code.google.com/p/javamelody/wiki/UserGuide#6._Optional_parameters):

> The parameter disabled (false by default) just disables the
>   monitoring. This allows for example to disable the monitoring
>   temporarily or only on some servers, from the tomcat context or from
>   system properties without modifying the web.xml file neither the war
>   file of the monitored webapp.

But maybe you can disable the whole monitoring by using the 'url-exclude-pattern' option. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

This could be disabled all meta programming by adding context-param javamelody.disabled in web.xml. So to avoid calling doWithDyanmicMethod part.